# Run a nodeJS code in a Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, redmine, redmine-plugins

How can I run a nodeJS code in a Redmine plugin ?
With a nodeJS server or from the controller or anything else ... ?

My plugin is an HTML button in a Hook, calling an onClick javascript function.
When I push this button, I want to run the nodeJs code. How can I do ?

I use Redmine 1.4.4

EDIT: maybe this can help me ? https://github.com/cowboyd/rednode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/41820?r=41882

```
From what I know, 3 scenarios:

    You want to use a publicly exposed NodeJS service. 
    In that case just make an ajax call to your service (jQuery).

    You want to use a non-public NodeJS service Run your NodeJS 
    service on localhost (listening to 127.0.0.1) and call it from the controller 
    of your plugin.

    You want to use a task (executable). 
    Run a system("/my/path/executable #{param}") command from the controller 
    of your plugin.

I don't like solution number 3 because there is more possibilities of something 
going wrong.
```